# Shouldn't change the others API token of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using "Matrix-based security" for Jenkins authorization with login users have all permissions. But the problem is all can able to change others API token. I can't restrict the users.

So, i need to restrict that operation alone.

Answer (score 0):

> [logged in] users have all permissions

That's the problem — you need to ensure only people that should have admin rights have the Overall > Administer permission.  Which is a good idea anyway.

There is no finer granularity of permission, that allows/denies people only to edit user accounts